# Mi pagina hecha con react js no redirecciona

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

Hice esta aplicación con un login hecho en react que consume api creadas en express con datos traídos desde una base de datos personal, mi problema es que al dar al botón de login debería tomar el id de la cuenta que se lee desde el login por medio de la ruta de express para navegar hacia la siguiente componente de react con las rutas hechas con **react-router-dom** pero al hacerlo suceden 2 cosas en el caso de la imagen adjunta como testeo retorna el valor del id que pensaba adjuntar a la ruta para desde ella consumir otra api con los datos de ese id, pero en ocasiones retorna el valor y en otras no, además no redirecciona correctamente sino que va a la siguiente ruta y se devuelve al login. La ruta **PerfilCliente** es un componente que retorna un hola mundo de prueba. El valor de respuesta es el 6 que se muestra en la consola, por lo que no creo que el error sea de la base de datos ni de express.

Archivo de inicio de react

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Rutas from './routes'

render (
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Rutas/>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Archivo de rutas de react

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import LoginCliente from './pages/LoginCliente';
import PerfilCliente from './pages/PerfilCliente';

const Rutas = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={LoginCliente} />
        <Route exact path="/perfilcliente" component={PerfilCliente} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

export default Rutas;
```

Pagina de usuario

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

import "./LoginCliente.css"

const Login = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  const [data, setData] = useState ({
    usuario: "",
    contrasena: ""
  })
  
  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    setData({
      ...data,
      [event.target.name] : event.target.value
    })
  }

  const sendData = async() => {
    await fetch('http://localhost:5000/logincliente', {
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    });

    const cliente = await pool.json()
    console.log(cliente.idCuenta);

    history.push("/perfilcliente");
  }

  return (
    <div className="login-container">
      <div className="login-title">
        <b>Client Login</b>
      </div>
      <form className="login-form" onSubmit={sendData}>
        <div className="input-container">
          <label><b>Username</b></label>
          <input type="text" name="usuario" onChange={handleInputChange}/>
        </div>
        <div className="input-container">
          <label><b>Password</b></label>
          <input type="text" name="contrasena" onChange={handleInputChange}/>
        </div>
        <div className="button-container">
          <button className="sign-in-button" type="submit">Sign In</button>
          <button className="admin-button">Login as Admin</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login
```

Archivo principal de express

```
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const cors = require('cors');

const loginClient = require('./routes/clientLogin.routes');

const app = express();
//port
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

//middlewares
app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan('tiny'));
app.use(express.json());
//routes
app.use(loginClient);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listen on port ${port}`);
});
```

Conexión de express con la base de datos

```
const getConnection = require('../config');
const sql = require('mssql');

const getIdAccount = async(req, res) => {
  const {usuario, contrasena} = req.body;

  try {
    const pool = await getConnection();
    const result = await pool.request()
        .input('usuario', sql.VarChar, usuario)
        .input('contrasena', sql.VarChar, contrasena)
        .execute('getIdCuentaAhorro');
    res.send({idCuenta: result.returnValue});

  } catch (err) { console.error(err) }
}

module.exports = getIdAccount
```

Ruta de login de express

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const getIdAccount = require('../controllers/clientLogin');

router.post('/logincliente', getIdAccount);

module.exports = router;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  const sendData = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault() // onSubmit form event

    fetch('http://localhost:5000/logincliente', {
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
    .then(response => {
      if(response.ok){
        const cliente = response.json();
        if(cliente && cliente.idCuenta){
           history.push("/perfilcliente")
        }
      }
    })
    .catch(e => {
        // Manejar (request error)
    })
  }
```

No olvides que el evento onSubmit repercute en la url del navegador, por lo que debes evitar su comportamiento por defecto... Eso podria ser parte de tu problema, el resto es manejar mejor la respuesta de la api. Te recomiendo usar axios sobre fetch.